# Is there any 96bit variable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to generate database items with ID consisting of 32bit timestamp, 48bit MAC and 16bits worth of iterator. While i can make this as a byte array no problem, it really complicates the use of the ID in vb.net... manageable but inconvenient.

I stumbled on the interopservices.StructureLayout thingies, which I think can be used to create structures sorta like unions in c++. This would enable me to easily access the various bits of the ID but i need some kind of variable to represent the ID as a whole too. Is there any 96bit type in vb.net? Or could i possibly create one?

Comment: Why not use a `Structure` (in a similar manner that `System.Guid` is)?

Answer (score 1):

You will be better off using System.Numerics.BigInteger that offers all operations available with regular integers. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx